# How to Embed video Popup in Office 365 Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-experience, sitepages

I have scenario in which I need to display text in which I need to show button once click on button it show video in pop up.

Is it possible in office 365 SharePoint? I can able to do text with link only but I need button click popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to show the dialog/pop up on button click using out of the box functionality.

If you are using text web part then you can create a hyperlink which will open a video/link in new browser tab Or you can use button web part to show button & open link in new tab (This is what you can achieve using out of the box web parts & not dialog/pop up).

Or

You need to develop a custom solution using SPFx as per your requirememts.

**Documentation**: [Overview of SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)

Comment: Thank you Ganesh!

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.